# Load the div content when that div is seen/reached while scrolling

Tags: jquery

On the jQuery documentation pages, I notice that the Disqus comments do no open until I scroll to that part of the page.

Scroll down the bottom of this page and you'll notice the affect: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

I was wonder how this was done as I would like to use it on my website as it will help reduce the page loading time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having a look at the source for that page, starting on line 461 or so:

```
jQuery(function(){
  var ds_loaded = false, 
      top = jQuery("#comments").offset().top,
      instructionsCloned = false;

  function check(){
    if ( !ds_loaded && jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() > top ) {
        jQuery.getScript("http://jquery.disqus.com/disqus.js?v=2.0&slug=child_selector_8220parent_child8221&pname=wordpress&pver=2.12");
        ds_loaded = true;
    } else if ( !instructionsCloned && document.getElementById('dsq-form-area') ) {

      var instructions = jQuery('ul.comment-instructions');

      instructions.clone().css({
        backgroundColor: instructions.css('backgroundColor'),
        borderWidth: instructions.css('borderWidth'),
        padding: '1em',
        margin: '1em 0'
      }).prependTo('#dsq-form-area');

      jQuery("#dsq-new-post > h3").text("Add a Contribution");

      instructionsCloned = true;
    }
  }

  jQuery(window).scroll(check);

  check();

});
```

They first get the offset for the top of the comments div:

```
top = jQuery("#comments").offset().top
```

then they define a function called `check()` that checks to see what the current scroll height of the window is and if that, plus the window height, is greater than the offset value then they load the disqus script:

```
if ( !ds_loaded && jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() > top ) {...}
```

Then they bind this `check()` function to the `scroll` event of the window:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(check);
```

tl;dr: Everytime you scroll the page, they are checking the height of the scroll against the offset height of the comments div and if it's viewable, then it loads the disqus scripts (which loads the comments).

HTH :)

Comment: clearly you spent a while writing this excellent answer, is there a reason you decided to leave the original question largely incoherent?

Comment: @Sam Saffron: To be honest, When I first read it, I didn't have an issue reading or comprehending it. If I look at it now, yes it's not the best wording. Normally I do make try and fix up questions but it just didn't occur to me on this one. I'll fix it up now :)

Comment: thanks heaps, I am just trying to figure out if there are ways to make the system "encourage" you more to do stuff like that

Comment: @Sam Saffron: I have posted a Meta question with some of my thoughts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91569/encouraging-question-editing-and-improving